# How to perform successive callback functions in node js with express?

Tags: node.js, express, callback, slack-api

I'm trying to build a slack app with a bot and to do so I need to perform several callback function but it didn't manage to launched the third one. The first two works well but the last one never starts and I don't know why.
I'm using express.

Here is my code :

```js
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());

var port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


//Fonctions de Callback
boutonSlack = function(req, res,next) { //Show the slack button to install the app
    res.send('<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=bot,incoming-webhook,commands,'
                                                         +'src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png" '
                +'srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, '
                +'https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x" /></a>');
    console.log('cb0:le bouton slack s\'affiche');
    next();
    app.get('/redirect/',recupCode);
};

recupCode = function(req, res, next){//get the code parameter to perform the oauth process
    console.log(req.query.code);
    process.env.CODE = req.query.code;
    console.log('cb1 : le code est récupéré');
    res.send('cb1 : le code est récupéré');
    https.get('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id='+process.env.CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+process.env.CLIENT_SECRET+'&code='+process.env.CODE, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            var result = JSON.parse(chunk);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            process.env.SLACKTOKEN = result.access_token;
            process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = result.bot.bot_access_token;
        });
    });
    console.log(process.env.SLACKTOKEN);
    console.log(process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN);
    console.log('cb2 : le token est récupéré')
    next();
    app.get('/',ouvertureWebsocket);
};

ouvertureWebsocket = function (req, res, next) {//perform the rtm.start slack method to open the websocket
    console.log('cb3 : ouverture du web socket');
    res.send('cb3 : ouverture du websocket');
    https.get('https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token='+process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            var result = JSON.parse(chunk);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        });
    });
    res.end(); 
}

app.get('/',boutonSlack);
app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Ready, listenning port '+port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to dig further on how asynchronous code works in nodejs

In your case, you must place

```
console.log(process.env.SLACKTOKEN);
console.log(process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN);
console.log('cb2 : le token est récupéré')
next();
app.get('/',ouvertureWebsocket);
```

inside `https.get('https://slack.com/api/rtm.start?token...` data callback.

```
https.get('https://slack.com/api/oauth.access?client_id='+process.env.CLIENT_ID+'&client_secret='+process.env.CLIENT_SECRET+'&code='+process.env.CODE, (res) => {
    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        // THIS CODE IS EXECUTED when HTTPS request from slack has finished
        var result = JSON.parse(chunk);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        process.env.SLACKTOKEN = result.access_token;
        process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = result.bot.bot_access_token;
        console.log(process.env.SLACKTOKEN);
        console.log(process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN);
        console.log('cb2 : le token est récupéré')
        next();
        app.get('/',ouvertureWebsocket);
    });
});
```